# parallel but different Slurm srun job step invocations not working

Tags: slurm

I'd like to run the same program on a large number of different input files.  I could just submit each as a separate Slurm submission, but I don't want to swamp the queue by dumping 1000s of jobs on it at once.  I've been trying to figure out how to process the same number of files by instead creating an allocation first, then within that allocation looping over all the files with srun, giving each invocation a single core from the allocation.  The problem is that no matter what I do, only one job step runs at a time.  The simplest test case I could come up with is:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 -c 1 sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 -c 1 sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 -c 1 sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 -c 1 sleep 1 &

wait
```

It doesn't matter how many cores I assign the allocation:

```
time salloc -n 1 test
time salloc -n 2 test
time salloc -n 4 test
```

it always takes 4 seconds.  Is it not possible to have multiple job steps execute in parallel?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It turned out to be that the default memory per cpu was not defined, so even single core jobs were running by reserving all the node's RAM.

Setting DefMemPerCPU, or specifying explicit RAM reservations did the trick.

Comment: I am having the same problem. I sequentially run 3 jobs with srun, but it gets stuck after first job. Could you share what exactly you added your script to fix the issue?
I use this but still I have error.

    #SBATCH --mem=0
    export DAEMON_MEM=${SLURM_MEM_PER_CPU:=4096}
    export SPARK_MEM=$((${DAEMON_MEM}*(${SPARK_WORKER_CORES} -1)))

Answer (score 5):

Beware that in that scenario, you measure both the running time and the waiting time. Your submission script should look like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

time {
srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 -c 1 sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 -c 1 sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 -c 1 sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks 1 -c 1 sleep 1 &
wait
}
```

and simply submit with

```
salloc -n 1 test
salloc -n 2 test
salloc -n 4 test
```

You then should observe the difference, along with messages such as `srun: Job step creation temporarily disabled, retrying` when using `n<4`.

Comment: Those are good suggestions, much appreciated.  The problem turned out to be something else though.

Answer (score 3):

Since the OP solved his issue but didn't provide the code, I'll share my take on this problem below.

In my case, I encountered the error/warning `step creation temporarily disabled, retrying (Requested nodes are busy)`. This is because, the `srun` command that executed first, allocated all the memory. The same cause as encountered by the OP. To solve this, one first optionally(?) specify the total memory allocation for `sbatch` (if you are using an `sbatch` script):

```
#SBATCH --ntasks=4
#SBATCH --mem=[XXXX]MB
```

And then **specify the memory use per `srun` task:**

```
srun --exclusive --ntasks=1 --mem-per-cpu [XXXX/4]MB sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks=1 --mem-per-cpu [XXXX/4]MB sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks=1 --mem-per-cpu [XXXX/4]MB sleep 1 &
srun --exclusive --ntasks=1 --mem-per-cpu [XXXX/4]MB sleep 1 &
wait
```

I didn't specify CPU count for `srun` because in my `sbatch` script I included `#SBATCH --cpus-per-task=1`. For the same reason I suspect you could use `--mem` instead of `--mem-per-cpu` in the `srun` command, but I haven't tested this configuration.